# How do I make an array of pointers and modify this array's values?

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, struct

I am trying to understand how an array of pointers work. However, I am having problems modifying this array.

I have the below struct for the nodes I wish to point to:

```
typedef struct StuNode *Node;

struct stuNode {
    char *stuName;
    int stuGrade;
};
```

In another function, I have created my array of pointers (SIZE here  is a constant) which I want to use so that every element of the array points to a Node:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void ModifyArray(Node *Array, int ArraySize);

int main(void) {
    Node *Array[3];
    Node stuOne = malloc(sizeof(*stuOne));
    stuOne->stuName = "Alex";
    stuOne->stuGrade = 7;
    Node stuTwo = malloc(sizeof(*stuTwo));
    stuTwo->stuName = "Bob";
    stuTwo->stuGrade = 8;
    Node stuThree = malloc(sizeof(*stuThree));
    stuThree->stuName = "Carl";
    stuThree->stuGrade = 9;
    Array[0] = stuOne;
    Array[1] = stuTwo;
    Array[2] = stuThree;
    ModifyArray(Array, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

The ModifyArray function looks like this:

```
void ModifyArray(Node *Array, int ArraySize) {
    Node *arrayOne[ArraySize];
    arrayOne[0] = Array[0];
    Node *arrayTwo[ArraySize];
    arrayTwo[0] = arrayOne[0];
    if (arrayOne[0]->stuGrade == arrayTwo[0]->stuGrade) {
        printf("check1/n");
    }
    if (arrayOne[0]->stuGrade == 7) {
        printf("check2/n");
    }
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to assign nodes from one pointer array to another, and I am also trying to figure out how to access the values of each node from my array of pointers (hence the checks I am trying to print).

However, whenever I try to do this, I receive the error: **"ArrayTest.c:45:17: error: member reference base type 'Node' (aka 'struct StuNode *') is not a structure or union"**.

**What is wrong with my code (I am unsure at whether I have made a mistake creating array, modifying the array or both) and how should I be modifying my array of pointers?**

Thanks

Comment: Don't hide pointers behind type-aliases. Because `Node` is really a `struct StuNode *` then your array `Array` is defined as `struct StuNode **Array[3]`. That means an assignment like `Array[0] = stuOne` is incorrect. It also means that you're passing the wrong type to the `ModifyArray` function.

Comment: Furthermore, you have the same problem in the `ModifyArray` function, where `arrayOne` and `arrayTwo` are wrongly defined. And the function doesn't actually modify anything in the original array. And you initialize both `arrayOne[0]` *and* `arrayTwo[0]` to be the exact same pointer.

Comment: Notice that you have different names `StuNode` (in `typedef`) and `stuNode` (the structure definition). Not sure, but that can be the problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, not sure if I understand you correctly. But, I think he is trying to define a type of `stuNode*` as `Node` and then use that type elsewhere. He has made some typo, because of which he is getting that error stating `StuNode is not a struct or union`.

Comment: Yes, @kiner_shah, I see that now, and I deleted my original comment.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the help! removing the additional * from my array declarations and changing the array that I send as a parameter into my function fixed all of the errors :)

Comment: @kxg, glad to help :-) I would recommend you to definitely review your code in case of errors. Reviews really help in finding the mistakes.